# Linking Microservices to test/dev/prod environments with ingress

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress

Let's consider we have three environments:

- `test.website.com`
- `dev.website.com`
- `prod.website.com`

Each of the environment consists of the following microservices: webapp, service1, service2. I want to be able to easily call all the services from JS frontend without having to deal with domains. It would be great if I could just call `/services/service1/` and the fact I am on the same domain would keep me in the same environment.

So let's consider dev environment:

- `dev.website.com/` -> goes to webapp
- `dev.website.com/services/service1/` -> goes to service1
- `dev.website.com/services/service1/` ...

To be able to do that, I configured ingress as follows:

```
    - path: /services/service1/*
      backend:
        serviceName: service1
        servicePort: 8080
    - path: /services/service2/*
      backend:
        serviceName: service2
        servicePort: 8080
    - path: /*
      backend:
        serviceName: webapp
        servicePort: 8080
```

This would work great, but it doesn't.

1. First issue is that the `service1` receives full path (`/services/service1`) instead of just `/` when being called. For that I found this: `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` - But I also foudn that this feature is not implemented, which is contradictory and doesn't make much sense.
2. Second problem is that, the order of the services is not followed and call on `/services/service1/` ends up in `webapp`.

Is this even a good approach? What is the best practice to do this?

**Edit**:

According to suggestions I removed `*` from the path, which helped, but also removed necessary functionality. I need to be able to use:

- `/en/` -> `webapp`
- `/services/service1/method1` -> `service1`

This doesn't work without the `*` in path.

Comment: "/serviceS/service1/ ends up in webapp" i think it should be "/service/service1/"

Comment: The approach is correct, but are you defining the host? Can you share 
`kubectl describe ing INGRESS` and the complete ingress file?

Comment: I fixed the `service` vs `services` issue in my question, thanks for mentioning that. I cannot provide full ingress as this is a fictive ingress yaml. I would have to provide our production one which I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 1):

1. According to the [documentation of nginx-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md), the annotation prefix is now `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` and not `ingress.kubernetes.io` as you used. You can change it with the argument `--annotations-prefix`.
2. Try to remove the wildcard (`*`) from your `path`:

```
- path: /service/service1
  backend:
    serviceName: service1
    servicePort: 8080
- path: /service/service2
  backend:
    serviceName: service2
    servicePort: 8080
- path: /
  backend:
    serviceName: webapp
    servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: ad 1) This would bean using `nginx` instead of `gce`, which we would like to avoid as we would loose a lot of advantages of `gce`. Can you elaborate more whether this is a good practice and if this is the way it should be done?

Comment: What features do you need from gce ingress? 
As Damiano wrote [here](https://medium.com/searchink-eng/kubernetes-ingress-gce-vs-nginx-controllers-1-3-d89d6dd3da73) and I agree with him:
`The default GCE ingress controller has limited functionalities. This includes the lack of support of TLS and for the whitelisting of IP’s. Furthermore, we noticed a massive delay when applying the configuration changes.`

Comment: Concerning the features: I was told that using nginx will lead to losing the native gce-ingress monitoring, HA, logging. I am not sure if it is true, but as I have just basic knowledge I cannot discuss that.

Comment: You can gain these features by setting up a gce Load Balancer that points to the service of the nginx controller.

Comment: Try to add both for each path, with wildcard and without.